# Windows 2008 Task Scheduler Problem

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008, console-application, scheduled-tasks

I've created simple .NET 2.0 Console application. Reads DB, sends emails and writes result to subfolder named "logs" as a .TXT file.

Application works when i run it manually.
But task scheduler can not able to run it.

When i looked the history i saw
"Task Scheduler successfully finished "{46794881-039f-4c37-8c5b-af70def503ce}" instance of the "\testtask" task for user "xxx\Administrator"."

And the last run result is "(0x1)"

What does it mean and how can i make this run?

thanks in advance...

OKB

Answer (score 2):

0x1 is likely to be the `ERRORLEVEL` that your process returned. 
Try invoking the command manually (ideally as the user who will be running the task). Remember it won't run as full administrator unless you tick the 'full access' checkbox.

Is it trying to touch files in a shared location that are owned by another user - if so change the file permissions.

The best way of figuring out what's *really* going wrong is to download procmon and find out rather than starting a guessing session.

Comment: i tried to invoke manually but stays same... i dont think this is a resource problem. set all file permissions for everyone

Comment: Then procmon is the best answer (Thats if stays same means "that works fine, unlike my timed task")